# How can I express this phrase symbolically? "There exist integers $m$ and $n$ such that $m \neq 0$ and $n \neq 0$ and $m^2 = 2n^2$."

Tags: logic

> "There exist integers $m$ and $n$ such that $m \neq 0$ and $n \neq 0$ and $m^2 = 2n^2$."
>
> I need to express this using logical symbols but I'm having trouble with where to place $m \neq 0$ and $n \neq 0$.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: $$(\exists n \in \Bbb{Z})(\exists m \in \Bbb{Z})(\lnot(m = 0) \land \lnot(n = 0) \land m^2 = 2n^2)$$

Answer (score 0):

Now, firstly, this is hard to answer because, depending on the logic that you're using, the symbols that you're allowed to use can vary! Either way, let's see what we can do. :)

I am going to assume that you are using $ L_{NN} $, which is a common abbreviation for the language of arithmetic, and that our universe of discourse, or domain, is the natural numbers including zero.

$ \exists m \exists n( ~\neg(m=0) ~\land ~\neg(n=0)~\land~(~(m \times m) = (2\times(n\times n)~)~)~)  $

Does this help?